# Install *gem file with bundle

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I try to develop a gem. I include it in my rails application through Gemfile with :path option for testing purpose, but there are some errors that appear when I build it and release to rubygems that does not appear when gem included from local path. How can I install gem from *gem file (made with rake build command) in rails or any bundle driven application for testing?

Comment: Not using the `:path` option is the default, so just use that after you releast. If your gem isn't ready for prime time, then release a `.pre` version and install it from Rubygems.

In the meantime try to figure out what's specific to it being local and focus on fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the best help: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

But in summary you need to build your gem from the .gemspec then using irb require your gem to test it out.

Example:

> > gem build hola.gemspec

```
% irb

require 'hola'

=> true
```

Comment: a question was about bundler